# What would cause a ticking sound and oscillating DC voltage on a SMPS based circuit board?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to fix a Wakins PN 1182201 REV E board. It's from a IQ2020 spa control system (approx 2008 era).

The system came in for repair as the system was accidentally sprayed with a jet washer.
The main IC (just below the transformer) let out the magic smoke, as did the PCB fuse. Also faulty were the 4x 1N4007 diodes that make up the bridge rectifier. I have replaced 4x diodes, fuse (T5A 250V) and the IC (TOP-255YN). Also I replaced most of the electrolytic capacitors around the transformer and the TOP255YN IC. The only capacitors I have changed in that area are the 400V capacitors near the bridge rectifier.

When you switch on the system the screen on the control head flickers (as if it is turning on and off) and you can hear a ticking sound.

The power supply appears to be SMPS design and I have ~312 volts DC +ve and 0 volts -ve going into the transformer, but an unstable (almost zero) voltage coming out.

---

UPDATE: 10/07/2023

I have measured voltages (DC volts) on the pins of the TOP255YN IC:

```
V = 2.99
X = 1.024
C & F = 5.8 (pins linked)
D = 312.3
S = 0
```

---

I have measured voltages at various points around the control board (after the transformer) and the only voltage I get oscillates from ~60mV +ve to ~60mV -ve.

The ticking sound happens approx every 300ms for 2-3ms.

### Questions?

1. What would cause the ticking sound?
2. What would cause the oscillating DC voltage?

FYI:
I don't have and can't find schematics for this board.

[image: control system]
[image: label]

Comment: Sounds like OCP hiccup. Probably something shorted on the secondary side. Can you measure the resistance across secondary side rail(s)? Inject DC voltage on it? Do you have access to a thermal camera?

Comment: Only seen this ... https://www.hottuboutpost.com/watkins-iq2020-main-control-circuit-board-77087-hot-springs/

Comment: Probably the little green electrolytic capacitor nestled in the heatsink. Capacitor dies and the TOPxxx follows suit. The circuit is probably much the same as the example in the TOPxxx datasheet. I’ve fixed a few power supplies with dead TOPxxx devices over the years.